# Synonyms Translation in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, seo

This is a little bit different scenario. I'm having a tool (C#.NET) which generates HTML content for a certain product site. Basically it contains products and descriptions so that the users can order it. These descriptions we are taking from the relevant manufacturers' sites. (Under their approval)

What happens is when we search this in google they identify the descriptions we have used as NON ORIGINAL and search results are not coming to the top.

Is there any way that we could put something like Synonyms translator into the tool so that while we copy the content from manufacturer the content will be changed with synonyms in our database. I'm not very sure about this. If you have any ideas please deliver here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are synonyms database vendors out there selling list of all words with associated synonyms. You can buy the list and perform string search & replace operations.

But the accuracy of the context is not 100% guaranteed.